# Django makemigration breaks when model query is run in form - Why?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am using Django 3.2

I want to populate a form select field as follows:

```
from .models import Post, BlogPostSubscriber, PostCategory

# This causes makemigrations to break !!!
# categories = [x for x in PostCategory.objects.all().order_by('slug').values_list('name', 'name')]

categories = [('',''),]

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
     
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['category', 'title', 'content','tags']

        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input'}),
            'category': forms.Select(choices=categories, attrs={'class': 'form-control input'}),
            'content': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control editable medium-editor-textarea'}),
            'tags': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input'}),
        }
```

When I run `python manage.py makemigrations`, I get the following error:

> Relation blog_postcategory does not exist

Why? and how do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

It's not migrations breaking, you won't be able to run the server either.

You can't do a query before the database is initialised, which is what happens when you are calling `PostCategory.objects.all().order_by('slug').values_list('name', 'name')` outside of a function or method.

Simply do:

```py
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['category'].choices = [(None, '')] + [(n, n) for n in PostCategory.objects.order_by('slug').values_list('name')]

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['category', 'title', 'content','tags']

        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input'}),
            'content': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control editable medium-editor-textarea'}),
            'tags': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input'}),
        }
```

Comment: The 'category' widget choices field is set to `categories`. Where is that variable coming from?

Comment: This gives error: `KeyError at /path/specified/in/route 'category'` on this line: `self.fields['category'].choices`

Comment: I just replicated this and it works for me. What do you get if you `print(self.fields)` before the line that causes the error?